# how to keep previous input

Tags: python, python-3.x

how do i keep previous input after i enter a new one? i want to make a list(not the built-in function) that keeps previous inputs and the most recent input...

my problem is when i enter an input after a previous one -it erases the previous and replaces it with the recent input

this is the smaller version of my current code:

```
enter = 1
count = 1
ctr = 0
max_input = 3


while ctr < max_input:

    for enter in range(1, max_input+1):
        if enter <= ctr:
            print("input " + str(enter) + ": " + str(user_input))
        else:
            print("input " + str(enter) + ": ___________" )

    user_input = int(input("enter number " + str(count) + ": "))

    enter += 1
    ctr += 1
```

this outputs:

```
input 1: ___________
input 2: ___________
input 3: ___________
enter number 1: 1
input 1: 1
input 2: ___________
input 3: ___________
enter number 2: 2
input 1: 2
input 2: 2
input 3: ___________
enter number 3: 3
```

expected output:

```
#the list before entering first number
input 1: ___________
input 2: ___________
input 3: ___________
enter number 1: 1

#the list after entering first number
input 1: 1
input 2: ___________
input 3: ___________
enter number 2: 2

#the list after entering second number
input 1: 1
input 2: 2
input 3: ___________
enter number 3: 3

#the list after entering last number
input 1: 1
input 2: 2
input 3: 3
```

Comment: You keep overwriting the `user_input` variable, which can only store one value. You want a variable that can hold multiple values, like a `list`. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: how do i store inputs in list? ...nvm -got it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of continually printing and overwriting `user_input`, which will have its old content deleted whenever you reassign it, you should store the data in a list. This lets you store multiple values in the same data structure. Here's an example of your code using lists instead:

```
# enter = 1    This line doesn't serve any purpose.
count = 1
ctr = 0
max_input = 3
input_list = []


while ctr < max_input:

    for enter in range(0, max_input):
        if enter < ctr:
            print("input " + str(enter+1) + ": " + str(input_list[enter]))
        else:
            print("input " + str(enter+1) + ": ___________" )

    user_input = int(input("enter number " + str(count) + ": "))
    input_list.append(user_input)

    # enter += 1      This line doesn't serve any purpose.
    ctr += 1
```

We still save the input to `user_input`, but then it's added to `input_list`, which stores an increasingly large number of values. You access the first element with `input_list[0]`, the next with `input_list[1]`, and so on. Notice that the first element of a list is at index `0`, not `1`.

Comment: i tried this but got this error "IndexError: list index out of range" ..i tried to fixed it by adding the variable i = 0, and used it for input_list[i] ..i added i += 1 at the bottom so the accessed element differes every loop...but the error still persists

Comment: @user3921890 if you've only added two elements to a list, and you try to access the third or something, that's how you get that error. That line with `input_list[enter]` is tied to `for enter in range(0, max_input)`, because you want a different list item every time through that `for` loop.

Comment: @user3921890 The `if enter <= ctr:` line should be changed to `if enter < ctr:`, since I changed `enter` so it starts at `0` instead of `1`. I edited my answer.

Comment: thanks! the error's gone..and it has solved most of my problem. however, the last input was still not displayed (which i forgot to mention in the original post)

Comment: @user3921890 that's because your `while` loop ends immediately after the user enters the final input, before it can be `print`ed out. You can change this by having one more `for enter in range` loop after the `while` loop that does the same thing.